# How to find unity and show subring

Tags: linear-algebra

let $\mathbb {R} $ be a commutative ring with unity $I_R $. Consider $s= \{nI_R |n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that $s$ is a subring of $\mathbb {R}$.what is the unity of $s$?

Sol : 
$0=0 I_R \in s$
let $a=n I_R $ , b = $ x I _R $ 
$a-b = I_R (n-x) \in s $
$ab =I_R ( n I_R x)\in  $ 
R is sub ring

Is true to show s is subring ? 
But I do not how to find unity 
Thanks in advance

Comment: $I_R = 1I_R$ is the unity.

Comment: Can  you explain more ?

Comment: Can you clarify what explanation you need? $I_R$ is the unity of $R$, so multiplying it by any element of $R$ (hence of $S$) gives you that element. Moreover, $I_R$ is contained in $S$ since we can write $I_R = nI_R$, where $n=1$. Thus $I_R$ is the unity of $S$.